# How to get file type by buffer number?

Tags: vimscript

As title. Currently, I only have the buffer number, I need to know which filetype it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`getbufvar()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#getbufvar%28%29) to get a variable definition, together with the `'&filteype'` syntax to get the value of an option rather than a variable.

```
:echo getbufvar(2, '&filetype')
```

Comment: was about 3 seconds late :)

Comment: @MaximKim: thank you guys!!